# Tray Selection in Google Cloud Printer

Tags: jquery, google-cloud-print

The requirement is to print different documents from different tray like the invoices from Tray 1, Envelops from Tray 2.

Is it possible to do with Google Cloud Print?

Comment: Please read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) The answer, *"A lot. An absurd amount. More than you think you are capable of. After you have reached the end of your rope and the pain of not having the answer exceeds the vast amount of shame received by posting your question, that's when you can go ahead and ask. Because at that point, you will have done whatever research necessary to make it a good question worth asking."*

Comment: Please read [Why is asking a question on “best practice” a bad thing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing/243450) before attempting to ask more questions that are opinion based that invite argumentative discussion because they do not have a single agreed upon answer.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Print does not include any CJT item to set the tray. It is not possible.